# HERE Mapview: How can I calculate the zoom level?

Tags: zooming, here-api, calculation

Example: I have a several coordinates and want to make sure that the static map image contains all of the points. Now I calculate the center coordinate. How can I calculate the zoom level so that each coordinate is included?

Answer (score 0):

First, add all points into a GeoBounding box to compute the bounding box of all the points. Next zoom the map using the following [API](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__zoomto-geoboundingbox-map-animation-float).

There are several variants of the zoomTo with GeoBoundingBox as the argument. This should cover most use cases you require.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have to specify my problem: I want to display coordinates on a map in Matlab. For that I use the Map Image API (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/topics/resource-map.html) which provides me an static image of a map. I cant use any functions. I can only use the parameters in the url to get what i need. My problem is that i need at least two coordinates in my image in order to calculate where all my other coordinates can be placed on the image.

Comment: I see, you are using our rest APIs. In this case, you need to implement the logic similar to what we have implemented on android and iOS. Compute and expand a GeoBoundingBox given your points. Given the GeoBoundingBox, compute the center of the geobounding box. Then use a recursive subdivision algorithm to find the best fit zoom level. IE: try 10, then 15, then 17 etc etc like merge sort until you find the best fit. That will allow you to compute the tile set which fits the bounding box on screen. Some math necessary for you :)

Comment: I could use a little more help with the math ;) Lets say I want a picture of europe. So I calculate a center coordinate, a zoomlevel and create the url: http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview?c=53.0014725,13.6456477&z=4.2&w=1116&h=692&t=14&f=0&nodot=1&app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX . Now I want to calculate the coordinates of the edges of the picture. How can I do that? My idea was to use the tilesize and the world radius to get the meter/pixel. But how do I know what tilesize is used when I use different widths, heights and zoomlevel? Is there a formula?